# Numpy Where and Pandas: How to aggregate groupby values?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How can I get an array that aggregates the grouped column into a single entity (list/array) while also returning `NaNs` for results that do not match the `where` clause condition?

```
# example
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'flag': [1, 1, 0, 0],
                    'part': ['a', 'b', np.nan, np.nan],
                    'id': [1, 1, 2, 3]})

# my try
np.where(df1['flag'] == 1, df1.groupby(['id'])['part'].agg(np.array), df1.groupby(['id'])['part'].agg(np.array))
# operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,) (3,) (3,) 

# expected
np.array((np.array(('a', 'b')), np.array(('a', 'b')), np.nan, np.nan), dtype=object)
```

Comment: Are the np.nan in part always aligned with the flag=0?

Comment: No, it is not the case that the np.nan in part is always aligned with flag=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the rows having `NaN` values in the `part` column, then group the remaining rows by `id` and aggregate `part` using `list`, finally `map` the aggregated dataframe onto `flag` column to get the result

```
s = df1.dropna(subset=['part']).groupby('id')['part'].agg(list)
df1['id'].map(s).to_numpy()
```

---

```
array([list(['a', 'b']), list(['a', 'b']), nan, nan], dtype=object)
```